# Xen Bridge Over VirtualBox Bridge

Tags: xen, virtualbox

**Short version**: Will a Xen bridge work over a VirtualBox bridge? If so, how does it work?

**Long version**: I have Debian 6 (Squeeze) 64bit installed as a guest in VirtualBox, which is setup as a bridge connection using my local NIC in my laptop (not wireless).

Xen installs fine and I can start VMs. However, bridge networking on Xen does not work. DomU systems do not get an IP address, and even if the IP is set statically I can't ping DomU systems.

In Debian, I added the line `(network-script 'network-bridge antispoof=yes')` to `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp`.

Creating a script `/etc/xen/scripts/network-wrapper` works with the following within it:

```
/etc/xen/scripts/network-bridge netdev=eth0 bridge=xenbr0 start
```

But if any changes are made to `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` and xend is started, then I will get the following error:

```
sigerr: command not found
```

Comment: Not to be rude but you do realize you are trying to run a hypervisor inside of a virtual machine monitor right all on top of another host operating system? I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but there's got to better way to do it.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am trying to do some testing with Xen, and taking snapshots with VirtualBox makes it really easy to go back when I make mistakes. I guess I will have to find a Linux backup solution and just install Debian on a real workstation. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to run Xen paravirtualization bridge from within VirtualBox. Just allow promiscuous mode in the virtual machine settings, and do not use a wireless NIC for the attached bridge adapter in VirtualBox. Here are my settings:

[image: VirtualBox Network Settings]

I tested both using Xen and a Debian bridge, they both work fine.

I know this is not convetional as stated by KCE, in the comment above, but it is a good setup for testing if you want to learn Xen, without having to use a seperate machine. So I hope this is of some help to someone else.